# C++ Code for find dependency of a given DLL file

Tags: c++, dll

I want to write a c++ program which lists down the dependencies of a given DLL file.

Exactly like  the `dumpbin \DEPENDENTS <file name>` command does.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Matt Pietrek's [PeDump sample](http://www.wheaty.net/downloads.htm). He shows how that works

Comment: The code is in available in C++!

Answer (score 0):

Use Microsoft's PE specification to known how .exe and .dll files are structured. Check also this:

http://alcides-mp.com/2012/03/exports-control/