# Get debug information from PE or PDB file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, pdb-files, portable-executable

I don't want to tell the whole story but all in all it would lead to this simple question:

"*Is there a way that allows me to read all stored debug information inside a PE or PDB file?*"

I am using the C/C++ compiler delivered by Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Use the [DbgHelp api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to do it for yourself, using C++, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993219/c-code-for-find-dependency-of-a-given-dll-file/10993260#10993260). Matt Pietrek the "urgestalt" for Portable Executable questions, shows how that can be done.

And [here](http://www.wheaty.net/downloads.htm), the link to his own list of samples.